# Unable to connect Robomongo to AWS EC2 via SSH

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, robo3t

After expending a lot of time I am here to put my problem.
My `MongoDB` server is running on `EC2` box with `centos` on port 27016.
I can easily connect through putty and use it to start Mongo cell with command

> mongo --port 27016

I just want to use same database with Robomongo `Robo 3T 1.1` version.

I have set SSH details on `SSH Tab` on Robomongo.

In connection Tab 
I have set host 127.0.0.1 and port is 27016(I am confused with it don't know it's valid or not).

I am getting this error

[image]

> After clicking on **show error details**

I am getting this message

[image]

> Note: My MongoDB server running on local machine on PORT 27017

***Thank You***

Comment: i think in your server didn't allow access port 27016. you can check this =). Hope this help

Comment: If you can connect with `mongo --port 27016` then that implies you have "externally" set up an SSH tunnel. So in RoboMongo you would simply use a standard connection to the different port, just like on the command line. If you use the SSH tab options, that's trying to set up a "new" tunnel. And will likely error. Just connect to the already tunneled port.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the comment, can you please elaborate your sentence `Just connect to the already tunneled port` because in connection tab I am using same `27016`.Can you please give me an example since in SSH tab I have connected with Private key.

Comment: The point is **don't put anything in the SSH tab**, If you connect over an **existing tunnel** on the command line then you don't need to create a new one.

Comment: @NeilLunn After login with putty on host e.g, 54.33.134.132:22, I run a script  on EC2 `abc.sh` which put me on centos box`(centos@ip-10-111-3-8)` in this box I use mongo --port 27016 to connect with mongodb.
So can you please suggest me which ip and port I need to put since I tested with both cases, sorry may be it's micro label question

Comment: Dude I have already "suggested" ( told you ) twice now, but for some reason it is not sinking in. If you can connect `mongo` like you show you have then port `27016` is clearly **already tunneled** to the remote server. That means the local port is set up to **forward all traffic** to the remote. **ALL TRAFFIC** includes all other tools. So **ANYTHING** need simply connect to the same exposed port. **NO NEED TO CREATE ANOTHER SSH TUNNEL**. Surely you cannot misinterpret that.